# How to Add a day on jquery calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I am using this code to create a jquery calendar on my page

```
$(function(){
    //set the datepicker
    var dateToday = new Date();
    $('#pikdate').datetimepicker({       
        minDate: dateToday,
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        defaultDate: '+1w'
    });   
});
```

how to add a day in this calendar that calendar should be start from after 24 hour.

Comment: which date picker plugin are you using?

Comment: jQuery UI Datepicker 1.9.2

Comment: Hi @AnkurSinghal I answered your question, let me know if it works for you. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this.

```
$('#pikdate').datepicker({       
      minDate: dateToday,
      dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
      defaultDate: '+1w'
});
```

Comment: I am also using this but i need a time also thats why i am using datetimepicker

Answer (score 0):

You could add a day in the date you are setting as "minDate".
See the example here (I changed your code):

```
$(function(){
   //set the datepicker
   var dateToday = new Date();

   dateToday.addDays(1); // it will add one day to the current date (ps: add the following functions)

   $('#pikdate').datetimepicker({       
      minDate: dateToday,
      dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
      defaultDate: '+1w'
   });   
});
```

But to make the "addDays" function work you must create the function as you can see down.

I always create 7 functions, to work with date in JS: addSeconds, addMinutes, addHours, addDays, addWeeks, addMonths, addYears.

You can see an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/tiagoajacobi/YHA8x/

This are the functions:

```
        Date.prototype.addSeconds = function(seconds) {
            this.setSeconds(this.getSeconds() + seconds);
            return this;
        };

        Date.prototype.addMinutes = function(minutes) {
            this.setMinutes(this.getMinutes() + minutes);
            return this;
        };

        Date.prototype.addHours = function(hours) {
            this.setHours(this.getHours() + hours);
            return this;
        };

        Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) {
            this.setDate(this.getDate() + days);
            return this;
        };

        Date.prototype.addWeeks = function(weeks) {
            this.addDays(weeks*7);
            return this;
        };

        Date.prototype.addMonths = function (months) {
            var dt = this.getDate();

            this.setMonth(this.getMonth() + months);
            var currDt = this.getDate();

            if (dt !== currDt) {  
                this.addDays(-currDt);
            }

            return this;
        };

        Date.prototype.addYears = function(years) {
            var dt = this.getDate();

            this.setFullYear(this.getFullYear() + years);

            var currDt = this.getDate();

            if (dt !== currDt) {  
                this.addDays(-currDt);
            }

            return this;
        };
```

They are propotype functions it means that every variable from the type "Date" will have this functions.